# get chunk where keyword appears

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to get information on variables and the only thing I have is the variable name. In this case let's say I need to get the chunk that belongs to `SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE` (every chunck starts with `<0>` and ends with `<0>`)

**In other words**  how can I get the chunk `<0>....SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE.....<0>`

Note I do not want to have `<0> ...... <0> ..... SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE .... <0>`

```
<0>
    temp
<0>
    fo0
<0>
    BLA BLA BLA
    kjfsd
    foodskjdsf
    kj
<0>
    someVariable
<0>
    SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE
<0>
```

So far I have tried:

```
<0>[\s\S]*?SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE[\s\S]*?<0>
```

that finds <0> and then continues until it finds SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE and stops until <0>

note that will select everything

my temporary solution is:

<0>[\s\S]{1,25}SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE[\s\S]*?<0>

this restricts the selection to less than 25 characters. I think this is to risky because there might be two chuncks smaller than 25 characters

---

### EDIT

In other words I want to end up with:

```
<0>
   SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE
<0>
```

and the only thing I have is `SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE` knowing that every chunk starts and ends with `<0>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.*?` you could use `(?:(?!<0>).)*`, like so:

```
<0>(?:(?!<0>).)*SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE(?:(?!<0>).)*<0>
```

But you might as well be better off splitting the string on `<0>` and checking which parts match `SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE`.

---

Note that the expression will never match the second "chunk" in:

```
<0> SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE   will match
<0> SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE   will not match
<0>
```

Because the second `<0>` is consumed by the expression, not allowing it to match. (The splitting approach does not have this problem.)

You can fix that by using a lookahead tho:

```
<0>(?:(?!<0>).)*SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE(?:(?!<0>).)*(?=<0>)
```

---

If you want `.` to match line breaks as well, add `(?s)` in the beginning of the expression, like so:

```
(?s)<0>(?:(?!<0>).)*SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE(?:(?!<0>).)*(?=<0>)
```

Comment: this is how I ended up using it becuase of the multilines:  `<0>(?:(?!<0>)[\S\s])*SOME_LARGE_VARIABLE(?:(?!<0>)[\S\s])*(?=<0>)`

Comment: @TonoNam, don't use `[\s\S]`, use `.` with `(?s)`.

Comment: When I tried your pattern it did not work. I had to replace the `.` with `[\s\S]`

Comment: Thanks! I will accept your answer as soon as stack overflow let's me.